# How to exclude a filetype when using the REN command in cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script which moves all the files from one folder to another and then renames them all to .jpg, however my .bat file itself gets renamed in the process because it sits in the destination folder. I need to exclude it from getting renamed.

Also, does the ren command exclude items in subfolders by default? I only want items in the destination folder renamed, not items in its subfolders.

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\Folder1" "C:\Folder2"
cd "C:\Folder2" && ren *.* *.jpg
pause
```

Comment: The `ren` command is not that fancy. You'll have to exclude it yourself. (Another option is simply to delete the batch file, then do the `ren`, then copy the batch file again.)

Comment: You could possibly `attrib +h "%~f0"` immediately before the `ren` and then `attrib -h "%~f0"` after `ren` as it seems that `ren` does not rename hidden files. Otherwise, a `for` loop can be used to iterate and rename each file and skip the batch-file when found.

Comment: Another possibility is using `cd "C:\Folder2" && (ren *.* *.jpg & ren "%~n0.jpg" "%~nx0")` which renames the batch file back before `cmd.exe` opens it again for reading the next command line.